# rolagem suave com javascript puro

Tags: javascript

Estou estudando javascript puro para sair um pouco do jquery então estou tentando recriar funções simples que eu uso no dia-a-dia e uma delas é a suavização do `scroll` mas n encontrei nada referente na internet alguém sabe como suavizo o `scroll` apenas com **javascript puro**? obrigado desde já.

Comment: Vc que algo tipo um btn "back to top" ou um que funcione no sistema de "ancoras" o que especificamente vc precisa?

Comment: pra falar a verdade os dois kkkk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aqui tem um exemplos simples apenas com JS puro. Não tem jQuery.

**Exemplo Rolagem interna suave apenas com Ancoras.**

```js
var smoothScroll = {

  move : function (old, des, actual) {
    easeInOutQuart = function (t) { return t < 0.5 ? 8 * t * t * t * t : 1 - 8 * (--t) * t * t * t; };
    actual += 1;
    ease = easeInOutQuart(actual / 100);
    delta = des - old;
    delta *= ease;
    delta += old;
    window.scrollTo(0, delta);
    if (actual < 100) {
      window.requestAnimationFrame(function () {
        smoothScroll.move(old, des, actual);
      });
    }
  },

  linkInit : function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    link = e.target.getAttribute("href").substr(1);
    block = document.getElementById(link).offsetTop;
    client = document.documentElement.scrollTop;

    smoothScroll.move(client, block, 0);
  },

  init : function () {
    links = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
    for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
      link = links[i].getAttribute("href");
      if (link.search("#") == 0 & link.substr(1) != "") {
        links[i].onclick = smoothScroll.linkInit;
      }
    }
  }
};

window.onload = smoothScroll.init;
```

```css
header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  height: 3vw;
  line-height: 3vw;
}
header nav ul {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0px auto;
}
header nav ul li {
  list-style: none;
}
header nav ul li a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.content {
  margin-top: 3vw;
}
.content .block {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#one">One</a></li>
      <li><a href="#two">Two</a></li>
      <li><a href="#three">Three</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>

<div class="content">
  <div id="one" class="block"></div>
  <div id="two" class="block"></div>
  <div id="three" class="block"></div>
</div>
```

Fonte: https://codepen.io/VicoTar/pen/mBqmBM?q=pure%20js%20smooth&order=popularity&depth=everything&show_forks=false

---

**Exemplo de "Back to Top" suave apenas com JS Puro**

```js
function getId(e){return document.getElementById(e)}
function showHideBackToTop() {
  var toTop_button = getId("scrollToTop-button");
  var scroll_position = window.pageYOffset;
  if(scroll_position>1000) {
    toTop_button.className = "";
  }
  else{
    toTop_button.className = "unvisible";
  }
}
window.addEventListener("scroll", showHideBackToTop);

function scrollToTop(){
  showHideBackToTop();
  window.scrollBy(0,-200);
  var s_position = window.pageYOffset;
  if(s_position >= 1) {
    setTimeout(scrollToTop, 10);
  }
}
```

```css
#container {
  position:relative;
}

#header {
  background:#333;
  color:#a7a7a7;
  font-weight:bold;
  font-size:25px;
  padding:30px 30px;
  text-align:center;
}

#content {
  max-width:640px;;margin:20px auto;
  font-size:20px;
  line-height:28px;
  text-align:justify;
  font-family:Cambria,serif;
  font-style:italic;
}

#scrollToTop-button {
  text-decoration:none;
  position:fixed;
  bottom:40px;
  right:40px;
  background:#333;
  color:#a7a7a7;
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  line-height:50px;
  text-align:center;
  border-radius:100%;
  transition:opacity 1s;
}

.unvisible {
  opacity:0;
}
```

```html
<div id='container'>
  <div id='header'>
  BACK TO TOP
  </div>
  <div id="content">
Morbi vel maximus nisi, quis tempor ex. In maximus lacus vitae ligula placerat mattis. Maecenas faucibus interdum mauris, non elementum urna. Cras vestibulum tellus nec hendrerit posuere. Suspendisse eget risus sit amet nibh iaculis sagittis. Curabitur lacus diam, rutrum eu sem et, iaculis euismod libero. Cras commodo ante in gravida molestie. Fusce lobortis sem et... <br/><br/>
Morbi vel maximus nisi, quis tempor ex. In maximus lacus vitae ligula placerat mattis. Maecenas faucibus interdum mauris, non elementum urna. Cras vestibulum tellus nec hendrerit posuere. Suspendisse eget risus sit amet nibh iaculis sagittis. Curabitur lacus diam, rutrum eu sem et, iaculis euismod libero. Cras commodo ante in gravida molestie. Fusce lobortis sem et... <br/><br/>Morbi vel maximus nisi, quis tempor ex. In maximus lacus vitae ligula placerat mattis. Maecenas faucibus interdum mauris, non elementum urna. Cras vestibulum tellus nec hendrerit posuere. Suspendisse eget risus sit amet nibh iaculis sagittis. Curabitur lacus diam, rutrum eu sem et, iaculis euismod libero. Cras commodo ante in gravida molestie. Fusce lobortis sem et... <br/><br/>Morbi vel maximus nisi, quis tempor ex. In maximus lacus vitae ligula placerat mattis. Maecenas faucibus interdum mauris, non elementum urna. Cras vestibulum tellus nec hendrerit posuere. Suspendisse eget risus sit amet nibh iaculis sagittis. Curabitur lacus diam, rutrum eu sem et, iaculis euismod libero. Cras commodo ante in gravida molestie. Fusce lobortis sem et... <br/><br/>Morbi vel maximus nisi, quis tempor ex. In maximus lacus vitae ligula placerat mattis. Maecenas faucibus interdum mauris, non elementum urna. Cras vestibulum tellus nec hendrerit posuere. Suspendisse eget risus sit amet nibh iaculis sagittis. Curabitur lacus diam, rutrum eu sem et, iaculis euismod libero. Cras commodo ante in gravida molestie. Fusce lobortis sem et... <br/><br/>Morbi vel maximus nisi, quis tempor ex. In maximus lacus vitae ligula placerat mattis. Maecenas faucibus interdum mauris, non elementum urna. Cras vestibulum tellus nec hendrerit posuere. Suspendisse eget risus sit amet nibh iaculis sagittis. Curabitur lacus diam, rutrum eu sem et, iaculis euismod libero. Cras commodo ante in gravida molestie. Fusce lobortis sem et... <br/><br/>Morbi vel maximus nisi, quis tempor ex. In maximus lacus vitae ligula placerat mattis. Maecenas faucibus interdum mauris, non elementum urna. Cras vestibulum tellus nec hendrerit posuere. Suspendisse eget risus sit amet nibh iaculis sagittis. Curabitur lacus diam, rutrum eu sem et, iaculis euismod libero. Cras commodo ante in gravida molestie. Fusce lobortis sem et... <br/><br/>Morbi vel maximus nisi, quis tempor ex. In maximus lacus vitae ligula placerat mattis. Maecenas faucibus interdum mauris, non elementum urna. Cras vestibulum tellus nec hendrerit posuere. Suspendisse eget risus sit amet nibh iaculis sagittis. Curabitur lacus diam, rutrum eu sem et, iaculis euismod libero. Cras commodo ante in gravida molestie. Fusce lobortis sem et... <br/><br/>Morbi vel maximus nisi, quis tempor ex. In maximus lacus vitae ligula placerat mattis. Maecenas faucibus interdum mauris, non elementum urna. Cras vestibulum tellus nec hendrerit posuere. Suspendisse eget risus sit amet nibh iaculis sagittis. Curabitur lacus diam, rutrum eu sem et, iaculis euismod libero. Cras commodo ante in gravida molestie. Fusce lobortis sem et... <br/><br/>Morbi vel maximus nisi, quis tempor ex. In maximus lacus vitae ligula placerat mattis. Maecenas faucibus interdum mauris, non elementum urna. Cras vestibulum tellus nec hendrerit posuere. Suspendisse eget risus sit amet nibh iaculis sagittis. Curabitur lacus diam, rutrum eu sem et, iaculis euismod libero. Cras commodo ante in gravida molestie. Fusce lobortis sem et... <br/><br/>Morbi vel maximus nisi, quis tempor ex. In maximus lacus vitae ligula placerat mattis. Maecenas faucibus interdum mauris, non elementum urna. Cras vestibulum tellus nec hendrerit posuere. Suspendisse eget risus sit amet nibh iaculis sagittis. Curabitur lacus diam, rutrum eu sem et, iaculis euismod libero. Cras commodo ante in gravida molestie. Fusce lobortis sem et... <br/><br/>Morbi vel maximus nisi, quis tempor ex. In maximus lacus vitae ligula placerat mattis. Maecenas faucibus interdum mauris, non elementum urna. Cras vestibulum tellus nec hendrerit posuere. Suspendisse eget risus sit amet nibh iaculis sagittis. Curabitur lacus diam, rutrum eu sem et, iaculis euismod libero. Cras commodo ante in gravida molestie. Fusce lobortis sem et... <br/><br/>Morbi vel maximus nisi, quis tempor ex. In maximus lacus vitae ligula placerat mattis. Maecenas faucibus interdum mauris, non elementum urna. Cras vestibulum tellus nec hendrerit posuere. Suspendisse eget risus sit amet nibh iaculis sagittis. Curabitur lacus diam, rutrum eu sem et, iaculis euismod libero. Cras commodo ante in gravida molestie. Fusce lobortis sem et... <br/><br/>Morbi vel maximus nisi, quis tempor ex. In maximus lacus vitae ligula placerat mattis. Maecenas faucibus interdum mauris, non elementum urna. Cras vestibulum tellus nec hendrerit posuere. Suspendisse eget risus sit amet nibh iaculis sagittis. Curabitur lacus diam, rutrum eu sem et, iaculis euismod libero. Cras commodo ante in gravida molestie. Fusce lobortis sem et... <br/><br/>Morbi vel maximus nisi, quis tempor ex. In maximus lacus vitae ligula placerat mattis. Maecenas faucibus interdum mauris, non elementum urna. Cras vestibulum tellus nec hendrerit posuere. Suspendisse eget risus sit amet nibh iaculis sagittis. Curabitur lacus diam, rutrum eu sem et, iaculis euismod libero. Cras commodo ante in gravida molestie. Fusce lobortis sem et... <br/><br/>Morbi vel maximus nisi, quis tempor ex. In maximus lacus vitae ligula placerat mattis. Maecenas faucibus interdum mauris, non elementum urna. Cras vestibulum tellus nec hendrerit posuere. Suspendisse eget risus sit amet nibh iaculis sagittis. Curabitur lacus diam, rutrum eu sem et, iaculis euismod libero. Cras commodo ante in gravida molestie. Fusce lobortis sem et... <br/><br/>Morbi vel maximus nisi, quis tempor ex. In maximus lacus vitae ligula placerat mattis. Maecenas faucibus interdum mauris, non elementum urna. Cras vestibulum tellus nec hendrerit posuere. Suspendisse eget risus sit amet nibh iaculis sagittis. Curabitur lacus diam, rutrum eu sem et, iaculis euismod libero. Cras commodo ante in gravida molestie. Fusce lobortis sem et... <br/><br/>Morbi vel maximus nisi, quis tempor ex. In maximus lacus vitae ligula placerat mattis. Maecenas faucibus interdum mauris, non elementum urna. Cras vestibulum tellus nec hendrerit posuere. Suspendisse eget risus sit amet nibh iaculis sagittis. Curabitur lacus diam, rutrum eu sem et, iaculis euismod libero. Cras commodo ante in gravida molestie. Fusce lobortis sem et... <br/><br/>Morbi vel maximus nisi, quis tempor ex. In maximus lacus vitae ligula placerat mattis. Maecenas faucibus interdum mauris, non elementum urna. Cras vestibulum tellus nec hendrerit posuere. Suspendisse eget risus sit amet nibh iaculis sagittis. Curabitur lacus diam, rutrum eu sem et, iaculis euismod libero. Cras commodo ante in gravida molestie. Fusce lobortis sem et... <br/><br/>Morbi vel maximus nisi, quis tempor ex. In maximus lacus vitae ligula placerat mattis. Maecenas faucibus interdum mauris, non elementum urna. Cras vestibulum tellus nec hendrerit posuere. Suspendisse eget risus sit amet nibh iaculis sagittis. Curabitur lacus diam, rutrum eu sem et, iaculis euismod libero. Cras commodo ante in gravida molestie. Fusce lobortis sem et... <br/><br/>Morbi vel maximus nisi, quis tempor ex. In maximus lacus vitae ligula placerat mattis. Maecenas faucibus interdum mauris, non elementum urna. Cras vestibulum tellus nec hendrerit posuere. Suspendisse eget risus sit amet nibh iaculis sagittis. Curabitur lacus diam, rutrum eu sem et, iaculis euismod libero. Cras commodo ante in gravida molestie. Fusce lobortis sem et... <br/><br/>Morbi vel maximus nisi, quis tempor ex. In maximus lacus vitae ligula placerat mattis. Maecenas faucibus interdum mauris, non elementum urna. Cras vestibulum tellus nec hendrerit posuere. Suspendisse eget risus sit amet nibh iaculis sagittis. Curabitur lacus diam, rutrum eu sem et, iaculis euismod libero. Cras commodo ante in gravida molestie. Fusce lobortis sem et... <br/><br/>Morbi vel maximus nisi, quis tempor ex. In maximus lacus vitae ligula placerat mattis. Maecenas faucibus interdum mauris, non elementum urna. Cras vestibulum tellus nec hendrerit posuere. Suspendisse eget risus sit amet nibh iaculis sagittis. Curabitur lacus diam, rutrum eu sem et, iaculis euismod libero. Cras commodo ante in gravida molestie. Fusce lobortis sem et... <br/><br/>Morbi vel maximus nisi, quis tempor ex. In maximus lacus vitae ligula placerat mattis. Maecenas faucibus interdum mauris, non elementum urna. Cras vestibulum tellus nec hendrerit posuere. Suspendisse eget risus sit amet nibh iaculis sagittis. Curabitur lacus diam, rutrum eu sem et, iaculis euismod libero. Cras commodo ante in gravida molestie. Fusce lobortis sem et... <br/><br/>Morbi vel maximus nisi, quis tempor ex. In maximus lacus vitae ligula placerat mattis. Maecenas faucibus interdum mauris, non elementum urna. Cras vestibulum tellus nec hendrerit posuere. Suspendisse eget risus sit amet nibh iaculis sagittis. Curabitur lacus diam, rutrum eu sem et, iaculis euismod libero. Cras commodo ante in gravida molestie. Fusce lobortis sem et... <br/><br/>Morbi vel maximus nisi, quis tempor ex. In maximus lacus vitae ligula placerat mattis. Maecenas faucibus interdum mauris, non elementum urna. Cras vestibulum tellus nec hendrerit posuere. Suspendisse eget risus sit amet nibh iaculis sagittis. Curabitur lacus diam, rutrum eu sem et, iaculis euismod libero. Cras commodo ante in gravida molestie. Fusce lobortis sem et... <br/><br/>Morbi vel maximus nisi, quis tempor ex. In maximus lacus vitae ligula placerat mattis. Maecenas faucibus interdum mauris, non elementum urna. Cras vestibulum tellus nec hendrerit posuere. Suspendisse eget risus sit amet nibh iaculis sagittis. Curabitur lacus diam, rutrum eu sem et, iaculis euismod libero. Cras commodo ante in gravida molestie. Fusce lobortis sem et... <br/><br/>Morbi vel maximus nisi, quis tempor ex. In maximus lacus vitae ligula placerat mattis. Maecenas faucibus interdum mauris, non elementum urna. Cras vestibulum tellus nec hendrerit posuere. Suspendisse eget risus sit amet nibh iaculis sagittis. Curabitur lacus diam, rutrum eu sem et, iaculis euismod libero. Cras commodo ante in gravida molestie. Fusce lobortis sem et... <br/><br/>Morbi vel maximus nisi, quis tempor ex. In maximus lacus vitae ligula placerat mattis. Maecenas faucibus interdum mauris, non elementum urna. Cras vestibulum tellus nec hendrerit posuere. Suspendisse eget risus sit amet nibh iaculis sagittis. Curabitur lacus diam, rutrum eu sem et, iaculis euismod libero. Cras commodo ante in gravida molestie. Fusce lobortis sem et... <br/><br/>

</div>
  <a id='scrollToTop-button' class='unvisible' href='javascript:void(0)' onclick='scrollToTop()'>TOP</a>
</div>
```

Fonte: https://codepen.io/kardinata/pen/woNPNX?q=smooth%20back%20to%20top&order=popularity&depth=everything&show_forks=false

Comment: vou testar aqui

Comment: funcionou perfeitamente vlw mano

Comment: Legal que deu certo! Eu não entendo muito de JS, mas quando preciso costumo consultar o Codepen, sempre tem coisa interessante por lá

Comment: eu acostumado com angularjs e jquery n parei para aprender o javascript puro mesmo ai agr to fazendo para um projeto rsrs